# Reading integers with fread in ANSI C

Tags: c, file-io, fread

I am writing a program in C, and I am reading a text file using `fread` and I cannot read correctly integers.

The value of `a` in the text file is 16, the output I get is:

```
 a= 538976288
```

I have used an analogous code that read successfully binary files. I would like to learn what is the best way to read ASCII tables in c.

The table size is given by the integers on the top of the file. The data are separated by spaces.

This is the simple code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a, flag_fread;
  FILE * p_finput = NULL;
  char * filename = NULL;

  filename = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(argv[1]) + 1));
  strncpy(filename, argv[1],strlen(argv[1]));
  filename[strlen(argv[1])] = '\0';

  p_finput = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (p_finput == NULL)
    {
      printf("couldn't open %s \n", filename);
      abort();
    }


  flag_fread = fread(&(a), sizeof(int), 1, p_finput);

  printf("a= %d \n", a);  

  fclose(p_finput);
  free(filename);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI: decimal 538976288 is hex 0x20202020; your code read 4 spaces from the text file into the `int`.

Comment: Note that [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) is not used for reading 'lines'; it has no clue what a line is, nor should it.  If you need lines, use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) (or, on POSIX 2008 systems, [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).  These are designed to read lines with appropriate line endings.

Comment: ok, fgets reads a string, but what should I do if I want to get numbers in a line?

Comment: Use `sscanf()` to convert the string into integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fread` reads the data in the file in its raw, binary form. Which works when the data was stored that way, with `fwrite` for example. When dealing with text you could use `fscanf`, **however** its use is recommended against because it does not do any bounds checking, which can cause buffer-overflows.

Better practice would be to read the file using [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) then use [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) to get the desired value. For example:

```
char buffer[100];
int itemsScanned = 0;
if(fgets(buffer, 100, p_finput) != NULL){
    itemsScanned = sscanf(buffer, "%d", &a);
}
/* check itemsScanned & continue */
```

Comment: this method works more or less, but I want to note that the manual says that fgets returns &buffer, or EOF on end-of-file or error, not the number of bytesRead. if I cast the value returned by fgets to an int I get most of the time a negative value and the if fails

Answer (score 3):

To read values written in text, you should use `fscanf`, like this:

`fscanf(p_finput, "%d", &a);`

Comment: because the actual file is constituted by a line with an integer followed by a table  with three column I was using fread to read each single line. I have also read that fscanf is not recommended.

Comment: Or, better, as `if (fscanf(p_finput, "%d", &a) != 1) { ...process error... }`.

Comment: ok, fscanf works. but I have to read a table, what do you recommend? and why does fread fail?

Comment: @simona: Do you know how big the table is before you read it? Do you know how many columns are in the table before you read it?  What about rows (or is it 'end of table' is at EOF)? Is there a fixed number of entries per line?  It helps to show what you're dealing with. The `fread()` function is designed for reading binary (rather than ASCII) data and is appropriate when you need to read large chunks of data without caring much about the contents, or when you need to read binary data previously written by `fwrite()`. Don't respond to this comment with another; add information to your question.